# Google Analytics EasyTracker in iOS not reporting

Tags: ios, sdk, google-analytics

I am not the developer on this app, but he tells me that he has correctly installed the EasyTracking functionality of Google Analytics in the iOS app.

I created a brand new account in Google Analytics and set it up as an "App". I also created a second profile on the same account that is just a standard "Web" profile, although without a specific URL attached to it.

After running the app for over 24 hours on multiple devices, I am getting NOTHING in the app reports - no screens, no events, nothing.

However, in the web reports, I can see the view controllers returning "hits" under content, almost like it was registering a hit on a web page.

Is there something above and beyond the basic EasyTracker integration that has to be done for this "App" reporting to get captured?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm seeing a similar issue: zero activity showing up on the GA realtime dashboard, even tho the debug printouts on the device claim the events were successfully dispatched

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your page views are firing but your event notifications are not.  If your account is receiving one and not the other, the problem is most likely due to code or that you're looking in the wrong spot, which doesn't seem correct.  Any chance you could post the page view and event code samples to look at?